# Отлов исключений из asm вставок

Tags: c++, windows, ассемблер, исключения

Как правильно ловить исключения из ассемблерных вставок?

Например, для такого кода

```
#include <iostream>
void foo()
{
    _asm
    {
        xor ebx, ebx
        div ebx
    }
}
int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

пытаюсь обработать так

```
#include <iostream>
void foo()
{
    try{
        _asm
        {
            xor ebx, ebx
            div ebx
        }
    } catch (...){
        std::cout << "exception";
    }
}
int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

, но исключение всё равно выпадает.

Компилятор: `VC++ 2015`

OS: `windows`

Comment: Поскольку ассемблерные вставки системно- и компиляторо-зависимы, имеет смысл указать ваш компилятор и операционную систему.

Comment: Вообще-то это совсем разные исключения... И механизм исключений C++ тут в полной мере ни при чем.

Comment: @Harry так как обрабатывать такие исключения?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Вам необходимо использовать обработку системных исключений, C++ к ним отношения не имеет. Подробнее можно почитать в [Structured Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657(v=vs.85).aspx). 
Конкретно для Вашего кода, это может выглядеть так:

```
 __try
{
    _asm
    {
        xor ebx, ebx
        div ebx
    }
}
__except(GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO ?
    EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH)
{
    std::cout << "exception";
}
```